# Create roboCopy script that backup whole drive

Tags: robocopy

I want to build a backup script using `robocopy`, but I haven't found any info on why I can't copy files that are open in another program when backing up `C:` to `F:`.

I've tried the below, but it's stuck on one file that is open by another program:

```bat
RoboCopy "C:/" "F:/" /E
```

What attributes should I use to skip directories `%WinDir%` and `Windows.old`, as well as only copy changed files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RoboCopy will be extremely inefficient at backing up a drive, and would not be recommended in any use case I can think of.

---

#### Commands

- For Windows >8, [`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) would be utilized to capture an image (*[WIM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats)*) of a drive:

  ```powershell
  DISM /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2017.07.14 @ 20:30" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
  ```

  - `/ScratchDir` is required, else the capture will likely fail since WinPE/WinRE only has 32MB of scratch [temp] space set aside for it by default.
- In Windows <7, [`ImageX`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx) would be utilized in lieu of DISM.

  ```powershell
  ImageX /Capture "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2017.07.14 @ 20:30" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
  ```

---

#### NOTE:

- **It's *impossible* for an ESD/WIM image to become corrupted**

  - Provided imaging commands are *always* issued with:

    - **Windows >8:** `/CheckIntegrity` & `/Verify`
    - **Windows <7:** `/Check` & `/Verify`
- **ESDs can only be taken of a *system* partition**

  - `/Compress:Recovery` is the only compression algorithm available.

    - ESD compression ratio is ~33% more efficient than the WIM compression ratio.
- **ESDs/WIMs are smart compression image formats**

  - Only changed files are added to an image when a new image is appended to it

    - Newly appended images utilize the same copy of unchanged files already contained within the image from the previous image(s).

      - This allows for an image to remain small in relation to the data contained within.

---

#### DISM Prerequisites

- **Easy**

  1. Download the *[Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)* & create a bootable USB/DVD
  2. Once booted from it, press: [**`SHIFT`**] **+** [**`F10`**] to open a terminal
  3. Issue *[DISM commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14)*

     1. *[Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image)* or *[Append](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#append-image)* an Image
     2. *[Apply Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image)*

        - Get *[Image Info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo)*, prior to applying, ensuring correct index is being applied.
- **Custom:** *Create a WinPE/RE image*

  1. **Install:** *[Windows ADK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-assessment-deployment-kit#winADK)*

     - **Select:** *Windows PE* & *Deployment Tools*

       - *Windows ADK (8 & 10, AIK for 7) is specific to the version of Windows installed.*
  2. **Create:**

     - *[Microsoft WinPE Wiki](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive)*

       - *[WinPE Optional Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference)*

         - *[Customize WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-mount-and-customize)*
         - *[Customize WinRE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/dn898523.aspx)*
     - *[Reboot.Pro Wiki](http://reboot.pro/topic/19156-create-a-bootable-winpe-50-x64-usb-drive/)*
  3. **Boot it**

Answer (score 2):

`Robocopy` has option `/XD` for excluding a list of directories:

```bat
/XD "C:\Windows" "C:\Windows.old"
```

You can get a list of `robocopy` commands, creating a text file on your desktop via:

```bat
Robocopy /? > "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\robocopy_commands.txt"
```

- If you want a current backup where both copies are identical, use the `/MIR` to  "mirror" the versions, which will delete files on the backup copy (destination) that are no longer present on the original copy (source); `/MIR` is a short-hand combination of `/PURGE` and `/E`.
- If you use the `/L` option, this will list what will happen, but won't actually do the move or copy, which is useful for testing your script before actually taking the time to copy stuff.
- `Robocopy`, at least when using `/MIR`, is restartable and does not re-copy things which have not changed.

To avoid massive slowdowns from problems opening or accessing files, I usually set the retries to some small number and the retry wait to a small interval, like `/R:2 /W:2`, and then check the log file for failures, handling those manually.

Comment: hey, what the option for skip "open\ise files"?

Comment: there isn't one. Use the retry and wait options as I suggested above so that the copy process will just move on. The default retry is something like 1 million. Set it to 1 or 2. The wait between retires is 30 seconds. set it to 1 or 2. Also, read the documentation.